# Are transaction compute costs static or variable?

Tags: transactions, compute-budget, compute

Do transactions with the same set of instructions (but just different accounts passed in) use the same amount of compute each time? Or is it variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an instruction like this :

```
pub fn my_instruction(
    ctx: Context<MyInstruction>,
    my_param: u64,
) -> Result<()> {
    let mut res = 0;
    if my_param == 1 {
        for i in 0..100 {
            res += i;
        }
    }
    msg!("res: {}", res);
}
```

We can clearly see, that if we provide `my_param` with a value of 1, our program will need to do more work than if we provide a different value (and the same applies for accounts if we had some if statement depending on the value of an account for example).

If you have a very simple instruction without any branch statements, it's likely that the Compute Budget will be constant, however you should generally speaking not assume this unless you go and look at the output of the compiled code; reason being that you never know what type of optimizations the compiler adds that might lead to non-constant Compute Budget in practice.

So to answer your question: **No, the amount of CUs used by an instruction is not fixed in general.**